# implementing push notification in ionic app

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement push notification in ionic app for Android.
I have followed step by step guide from http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-from-scratch.
When I am running my app on android phone, then the registered users are listed in apps.ionic.io. So user registration is working fine.
But device registration is not working.
It is giving error **Cannot read property 'pushNotification' of undefined**

This is my code at the top of app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova',
    'ionic.service.core',
    'ionic.service.push',
    'starter.controllers',
    'starter.services'])

    .config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider) {
        // Identify app
        $ionicAppProvider.identify({
            // The App ID (from apps.ionic.io) for the server
            app_id: '',
            // The public API key all services will use for this app
            api_key: '',
            // Set the app to use development pushes
           // dev_push: true
            gcm_id: ''
        });
    }])
```

Here is the code in of my controller

```
 .controller('DashboardCtrl', function($scope,$localstorage, WildfireService, CommonUtilityService,PushNotificationService,$ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {      
      PushNotificationService.identifyUser();
      PushNotificationService.pushRegister();

    })
```

Here is my services.js

```
 .service('PushNotificationService', function($q, $ionicUser, $ionicPush) {
        var PushNotificationService = this;
        PushNotificationService.identifyUser  = function(){
            var user = $ionicUser.get();
            if(!user.user_id) {
                // Set your user_id here, or generate a random one.
                user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
            };

            // Add some metadata to your user object.
            angular.extend(user, {
                name: 'Technews',
                bio: 'Hardcoded for now'
            });

            // Identify your user with the Ionic User Service
            $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function(){
                //alert('Identified user ' + user.name + '\n ID ' + user.user_id);
                return true;
            });
        },

        PushNotificationService.pushRegister = function(){
            // Register with the Ionic Push service.  All parameters are optional.
            $ionicPush.register({
                canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
                canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
                canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
                canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
                onNotification: function(notification) {
                    // Handle new push notifications here
                    // console.log(notification);
                    alert(notification);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

Can any one tell me where is the error or what I am missing?

I have added these in index.html

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-service-push/ionic-push.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally push notification is working for me.  I moved the function call of pushRegister from controller to identifyUser function. So here is the new working code for me.
Controller code

```
.controller('DashboardCtrl', function($scope,$localstorage, WildfireService, CommonUtilityService,PushNotificationService,$ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {      
      PushNotificationService.identifyUser();


    })
```

Here is new services.js

```
 .service('PushNotificationService', function($q, $ionicUser, $ionicPush) {
            var PushNotificationService = this;
            PushNotificationService.identifyUser  = function(){
                var user = $ionicUser.get();
                if(!user.user_id) {
                    // Set your user_id here, or generate a random one.
                    user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
                };

                // Add some metadata to your user object.
                angular.extend(user, {
                    name: 'Technews',
                    bio: 'Hardcoded for now'
                });

                // Identify your user with the Ionic User Service
                $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function(){
                    //alert('Identified user ' + user.name + '\n ID ' + user.user_id);
PushNotificationService.pushRegister();
                    return true;
                });
            },

            PushNotificationService.pushRegister = function(){
                // Register with the Ionic Push service.  All parameters are optional.
                $ionicPush.register({
                    canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
                    canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
                    canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
                    canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
                    onNotification: function(notification) {
                        // Handle new push notifications here
                        // console.log(notification);
                        alert(notification);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this new Ionic push notifications. I succesfully implemented push notifications in my Ionic App with ngCordova's push plugin for both Android an iOS (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) just by following the examples there. The key is to put the code in the .run module in app.js.

Here is the code:

```
angular.module('notPush', ['ionic','notPush.controllers','notPush.factorys','ngCordova','ionic.service.core'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $http, $cordovaPush) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    // Manejador de notificaciones push para Android
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){

      var androidConfig = {
        "senderID": "94XXXXXXXXXX", // ID HERE
        "ecb": "window.casosPush"
      };

      try{
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
      } catch (ex){

      }

      // Llamada en caso de exito
      var successfn = function(result){
        alert("Success: " + result);
      };

      // Llamada en caso de error
      var errorfn   = function(result){
        window.alert("Error: " + result);
      };

      // Llamada de casos de notificacion push
      window.casosPush = function(notification){
        switch (notification.event){
          case 'registered':
            if (notification.regid.length > 0){
              alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
            }
            break;

          case 'message':
            alert(JSON.stringify([notification]));
            break;

          case 'error':
            alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
            break;

          default:
            alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
            break;
        }
      };
      try{

        // Llamada de registro con la plataforma GCM 
        pushNotification.register(successfn,errorfn,androidConfig);
      } catch(notification){

      }
    }
})
```

Just remember to install the plugin with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```